# Rails, Amazon SES via SMTP, and tagging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ses

I love the simplicity of SES with rails, it's just another ActionMailer SMTP endpoint, but is there a way to tag outgoing messages per this instruction:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-using-event-publishing.html

Or must you use the API directly rather than SMTP to tag messages?

Thanks,
Kevin